# Potential verbs with and without ようになる

Tags: potential-form

According to http://www.guidetojapanese.org/surunaru.html:

> Since potential verbs describe a state of feasibility rather than an
>   action [...] it is [sic] often used in conjunction with 「～ようになる」 to describe
>   a change in manner to a state of feasibility [...]
>
> （１）　日本に来て、寿司が食べられるようになった。
>   - After coming to Japan, I became able to eat sushi.
>
> （２）　一年間練習したから、ピアノが弾けるようになった。
>    - Because I practiced for one year, I became able to play the piano.
>
> （３）　地下に入って、富士山が見えなくなった。
>   - After going underground, Fuji-san became not visible.

Why does sentence (3) not use ようになる? What is the difference with the other two cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To correctly and naturally use the construct:

> 「Potential Verb + ようになる」

the potential verb needs to be in the **affirmative** form as shown in the examples you quoted -- 「食{た}べられるようになる」 and 「弾{ひ}けるようになる」.

There is no 「ように」 used in the last example 「**見えなく**なった」 because it uses the **negative** form of 「見える」.

Thus, the correct forms are:

Affirmative (to become able to): **食べられる**ようになる、**弾ける**ようになる、**見える**ようになる, etc.

Negative (to become unable to): **食べられなく**なる、**弾けなく**なる、**見えなく**なる, etc.

A bit tricky, I know, but this grammar point is very important and useful.