# Can someone break down this sentence for me?

Tags: translation, particles, syntax, sentence, japanese-to-english

「人は話せるようになるとすぐ いろいろなことを尋ねます」I would like this sentence to be broken into Subject, Object, Verb... I can only distinguish a few of the particles, and I understand (because of dictionary) that「話せる」means to talk,「尋ね」is 'to ask' and「人は」is people, but I am confused a bit about what is fully making the sentence. Please help..

Comment: I suspect this portion is meant to be 「人は話せるようにな[る]{L}と」 ?

Comment: This might help you understand 〜ようになる: [Potential verbs with and without ようになる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72338/43676)

Comment: And this is for 〜と: [Differences among -たら、なら、-んだったら、-えば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/43676)

Comment: @istrasci yes I forgot to add that

Comment: @aguijonazo thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

- **人は**: "as for humans" (noun + topic marker)
- **話せる**: "to be able to talk; can talk" (potential form of 話す "to talk")
- **～ようになる**: "to come to ～; to reach the point where ～" (see [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-you-ni-naru-meaning/))
- **と**: "if; when(ever); once" (conjunctive particle, see [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8-to-meaning-whenever/))
- **すぐ**: "soon" (adverb)
- **いろいろなことを**: "various things" (noun phrase + object marker)
- **尋ねます**: "to ask" (ichidan verb in polite form)

All in all, the sentence literally means "As for humans, once [they] reach the point where [they] can talk, [they] soon ask various things". You can translate it more naturally like "As soon as a person learns to talk, they start to ask various questions."

Comment: This sounds strange to use 人.  Like, why wasn't it 赤ちゃん or something?

Comment: By not using 赤ちゃん, this sentence can also apply to non-native speakers learning a new language. As for *why* 人は is required here, https://note.com/asaokitan/n/n4e1b9dc24a26 gives a nice explanation.

Comment: @istrasci I don't think 人 is unnatural because it's the shared topic of the entire sentence. Someone who can ask a lot of question is no longer an 赤ちゃん. Besides, this sentence is using only the simplest grammar points (it doesn't even say 尋ね**始め**ます), so someone who wrote this might have thought 赤ちゃん was too difficult.

Comment: @naruto:  話せるようになったら、どう呼ばれる？「幼児」?「小児」?

Comment: @istrasci 「子ども」じゃないですかね…